# Read List in 1 thread, Write in another

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, tcp

I'm trying to create a windows service that when a file arrives to an FTP location, sends a message over TCP to the relevant user. I've got all the file detection parts set up, but I need some help on the messaging side.

As there will be multiple users subscribing to this service at the same time, it needs to be able to handle multiple connections, so I create the TCPServer server when the service starts, and begin listening for incoming connections. When one arrives, the code adds the connection to a list of connections.

So far, so good.

The problem arises when an incoming file triggers the sending of a message to the relevant client. Trying to access the list of connections fails, as I have to do it from a separate thread (since the thread listening for new connections cannot do anything else in the meantime).

Running this in debug mode, I see that the New Connection correctly increments the count of the ClientList, but when the debugger returns to the class to send the message, the ClientList variable is reset to 0, as I've had to create a new instance of the class. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

My code is below:

```
namespace WindowsService1
{
    class MSGServer
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        Int32 port = 13000;
        IPAddress localAddr;
        List<ClientConn> ClientList = new List<ClientConn>();
        Byte[] data;

        private object l_lock = new object();

        public void CreateServer()
        {
            localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("172.26.114.71");

            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            server.Start();

            NewConnection();
        }

        public void NewConnection()
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            while (true)
            {
                ClientConn Client = new ClientConn();
                Client.TClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = Client.TClient.GetStream();

                data = new Byte[256];
                String MSG = String.Empty;

                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                Client.ClientUserName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                stream.Write(data, 0, bytes);

                lock (ClientList)
                {
                    ClientList.Add(Client);
                }

            }



        }


        public Boolean SendNotification(string UserName, string FFolder, string FName)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            NetworkStream Stream;
            bool MsgSent = false;
            foreach (ClientConn Client in ClientList)

            {
                if (Client.ClientUserName == UserName)
                {
                    Byte[] MsgByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FFolder + "|" + FName);
                    Stream = Client.TClient.GetStream();
                    Stream.Write(MsgByte, 0, MsgByte.Length);
                    MsgSent = true;
                }
            }

            return MsgSent;
        }

        public void CLoseAllConnections()
        {
            foreach (ClientConn ConnToClose in ClientList)
            {
                ConnToClose.TClient.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    class ClientConn
    {
        private string CUser;
        TcpClient Client;

        public string ClientUserName
        {
            get { return CUser;}
            set { CUser = value; }
        }

        public TcpClient TClient
        {
            get { return Client; }
            set { Client = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

UPDATE: Resolved the problem I was talking about below by passing the instance of the class that runs CreateServer() to the thread that eventually calls the SendNotification method. Thanks for all your help

Comment: `List` is not designed to be concurrently modified and accessed from different threads.  You should be using a collection type that is specifically designed for that purpose.  A `BlockingCollection` should be just fine for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`BlockingCollection(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

```
class MSGServer
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    Int32 port = 13000;
    IPAddress localAddr;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<ClientConn> ClientList = new BlockingCollection<ClientConn>();
    Byte[] data;

    public void CreateServer()
    {
        localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("172.26.114.71");

        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        server.Start();

        NewConnection();
    }

    public void NewConnection()
    {
        Debugger.Break();

        while (true)
        {
            ClientConn Client = new ClientConn();
            Client.TClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = Client.TClient.GetStream();

            data = new Byte[256];
            String MSG = String.Empty;

            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            Client.ClientUserName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            stream.Write(data, 0, bytes);

            ClientList.Add(Client);
        }
    }

    public Boolean SendNotification(string UserName, string FFolder, string FName)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        NetworkStream Stream;
        bool MsgSent = false;

        foreach (ClientConn Client in ClientList.GetConsumingEnumerable().Where(c => c.ClientUserName == UserName))
        {
            Byte[] MsgByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FFolder + "|" + FName);
            Stream = Client.TClient.GetStream();
            Stream.Write(MsgByte, 0, MsgByte.Length);
            MsgSent = true;
        }

        return MsgSent;
    }

    public void CLoseAllConnections()
    {
        foreach (ClientConn ConnToClose in ClientList)
        {
            ConnToClose.TClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will try this when I get into the office. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm still doing something wrong, as when the SendNotification method is called, the ClientList resets to 0. When I call it, i've written
    `MSGServer MSG = new MSGServer();
            foreach (string User in RequestingUserList)
            {
                MSG.SendNotification(User, FFolder, FCurrentSearch);
            }
            Conn.Close();`

Comment: The `GetConsumingEnumerable` will consume the current items in the blocking collection. If you need to preserve the items then replace it with `ToList` which will create a copy.